# how to send nested data using jquery

Tags: jquery, django, django-models

i have i list of category populated using radio buttons and for each category i have a list of sub categories. when a category is selected then we can choose multiple subcategories using checkboxes.How can i wrap this data and send to my view.

here is the script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var parameter = [] ;

  $('#brand_category').click(function(event){
        parameter.push({
          brand :   $("input[type='radio']:checked").val(),
          category: $("input[type='checkbox']:checked").val()
          })

        console.log(parameter)

        $.ajax({        
              type: "post",
              url: "{% url 'seller_details' %}",
              data: { 'parameter[]' : parameter , csrfmiddlewaretoken:'{{csrf_token}}'},
              success: function(data) {
                $('#loading-image').hide();
              },
              error: function(response, error) {
              }
          });
      });
```

then in the view

```
list_data = self.request.POST.get('parameter[]')
```

here is the html

```
    <div id="catmodal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog" style="width:800px">
    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content"style="height: 450px">
      <div class="modal-header text-center">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Select Brand & Category</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">

        <div class="modal-left">
          <ul>
            <div class="heading">Brands</div>
          {% for brand in brands %}
            <li><input type="radio" value="{{brand.title}}" name="brand">{{brand.title}}</li>
          {% endfor %}
          </ul>
        </div>

         <div class="modal-right">
          <ul>
            <div class="heading">Categories</div>
          {% for category in categories %}
            <li><input type="checkbox" value="{{category.title}}"> {{category.title}}</li>
          {% endfor %}
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="submit" id="brand_category">
  </div>
</div>
```

how can i achieve this.thank you

Comment: bomb us with your html please :)

Comment: @madalinivascu included the html

Comment: how do you know which category is which brand?

Comment: for a selected brand using radio button i need to send the selected categories

Comment: That html is invalid. `<div>` can't be child of `<li>` . Also you will only ever have the value of one checkbox. Logic needs some fixing up

Comment: what can be the proper way then?

Answer (score 0):

Try `list_data = self.request.POST.getlist('parameter[]')`.

Comment: i get object Object in the View...how can i retrieve the data from it?

Comment: Does `list_data['brand']` give you access?

Comment: What is the output of `console.log(parameter)`

Comment: [Object]0: Objectbrand: "dp"category: "men"__proto__: Objectlength: n.js:3

Comment: In your view what does `print list_data` give you?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103728/discussion-between-adrafe-rinzzler-and-nanor).